# Simulink 3D Animation using VRML

Tags: simulink, vrml

I've set up an animation of a tugboat [from VRML library] using the Virtual Reality Animation objects. but am having trouble with viewing the rotation of the boat.

To be more specific: I have a simulator going, where I calculate from rigid body dynamics the trajectory of it in time. This is, I have x, y, z, phi, theta, psi vs. time. I associate the translations and rotations to the node corresponding to the boat. When pressing play, I can see the translation and rotation which is not as expected.

Not sure what the problem could be. I tried to add one Transform in the .wrl for each of the rotational degrees of freedom, but I found it weird as when I give rotation in one direction I see the object rotating and translating other directions as well.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: To be more specific: I have a simulator going, where I calculate from rigid body dynamics the trajectory of it in time. This is, I have x, y, z, phi, theta, psi vs. time. I associate the traslations and rotations to the node corresponding to the boat. When pressing play, I can see the translation and rotation which is not as expected. 
Not sure what the problem could be. I tried to add one Transform in the .wrl for each of the rotational degrees of freedom, but I found it weird as when I give rotation in one direction I see the object rotating and translating other directions as well.

Comment: You still have not asked any question. Please expand your post with more details, and ask a question. There should be at least one question mark (`?`) in it.